# Is this foreign job offer via an online agency without any interview legit?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I live in Saudi Arabia. I applied online for a job at a company in the UK through an agency. The agency sent me back an online job interview application that I have to fill in and sent back to them. After a couple of weeks the agency sent me a job offer to be signed from my side, and it asked me to contact a travel agent working with them so that they can furnish me with details on how to get the named document and help in the procurement of my UK Visa and other travel documents that will be needed from me to proceed to the UK.

The agency did not ask me for my certificates, and did not conduct an online interview through telephone or Skype.

Should I worry? Should I ask them to conduct an interview?

Comment: If the company or the 'travel agent' starts to ask you money to get X or Y done, or get the Z paper, or any very personal details, then you'll start to smell a scam.

Comment: It's a scam. The fraud warning is RIGHT ON THEIR HOMEPAGE. It's baffling to me that you would consider working for a company, where you haven't even looked at their website yet. What type of research did you do ?

Comment: Have you sent them any information that could be  used e.g. to open a bank account or get a credit card in your name? They may be doing identity theft in addition to trying to collect money for visa fees, tickets, and anything else they can think of.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I was thinking the same thing. If you're sending in an application, that most likely contains all (or most) of your personal information that can be used as part of identity theft, regardless of actually sending them money.

Comment: **Update your question** with proper links to the companies you are referring too. Don't let us (smci especially) have to dig up what companies you are referring to.

Comment: @JanDoggen If OP were willing to actually look up the websites to the companies in question, he would have seen the fraud warning on the company's website.

Comment: In my humble opinion this question should be sanitized to remove the company's name.  What is your stance?  I have created a meta question to discuss the topic.  Please weigh in [here](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/4109/is-it-ok-to-name-and-shame)

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the names of the companies involved.  It might be a good idea to sanitize the edit history if you agree with the edit.

Comment: after applying for this job through the agency , the company itself contacted me though its email asking me to fill the online interview form, the form does not ask for any detailed information that can be used for theft . i also had checked the company profile and i did not see the Fraud warning on their home page. i also reopened their home page right now but no warnings on it !!

Answer (score 166):

It's a scam. Info on their homepage about this [here](http://www.hfweb.co.uk/klpharm/)

> If you have received an e-mail offering you a position in our company
>   or the offer of help with your immigration to the UK, please be aware
>   that these offers are fraudulent and we suggest that you contact
>   Action Fraud at www.actionfraud.police.uk or on 0300 123 2040 using
>   Crime Ref: NFRC161201652124. Do not send personal details or money to
>   these scammers.

Answer (score 30):

## Yes, you should worry.

They are either malicious or incompetent if they send out job offers to people they've never talked to.

You should find a website and phone number for the company and give them a call, at least. Don't start making travel plans before you've talked to a human being.